# Ratio of standard deviations

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation

I have paired data.

I do not have the individual data points - solely the means and standard deviations at measurement 1 (m1, sd1), at measurement 2 (m2, sd2), and also the correlation coefficient between the values obtained at measurement 1 and those obtained at measurement 2 (r).

I would like to find the mean and the standard deviation of the ratio between these two measurements. The answer as regards the mean is trivial : m1/m2, but I am stuck as regards calculating the standard deviation. There is a formula given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty  I have used the formula here ( f=aA-bB ) to compute the difference  in standard deviations successfully, but I am unsure as to how to use the one to compute the ratio of standard deviations using the f=A/B formula.

I would be most grateful if anoyone is able to offer an advice.

Many thanks

Rob

Comment: The estimate of the mean is far from trivial: for many purposes, the ratio of the sample means is a poor estimate of the ratio of the true means.  It can be corrected using the SDs and the correlation.  However, whether and how to correct it depends on why you are making this estimate (more specifically, on what it costs you when your estimate is wrong). The same applies to the ratio of SDs: could you explain what you intend to use this ratio for?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For current purposes I am solely trying to calculate the sample ratios and for that the ratio of mean equals m1/m2. What I am unsure of is how to calculate the SD ratio.  As regards what the ratio is for - the measures are of regions of brain activity and I want to examine the ratio of various regions to one another.

Comment: You cannot divide the sample means to get the ratio mean.  The methodology is at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioDistribution.html  

Because of the correlations, both of those ratios are going to be ugly.

Comment: If all you care about is the sample ratios, then why is there any problem with the SD ratio?  Just compute it.  But I don't actually believe you: if you're trying to deduce something about "the brain" rather than just this particular sample, then you are making an estimate.  The ratio of means of this sample is unlikely to equal the ratio you are really interested in--and it could be pretty far off.